# A Wordpress Page to display custom database query results

Tags: php

I am quite new to WordPress. I want to create a report page where I can put some Html and PHP code to query MySQL database and show the result as HTML. If I create a page from Pages option - I can not put any PHP code inside it - Can I?

Once that page is set up, the admin user can go to that page to see the report.

What is the best approach for it?
1. Plugin
2. Create a php file 
3. Create a block (Not reusable functionality though - just for the specific page)
4. Any other approach

I tried to find out several plugins but none of them is free and allows what I am willing to do.

Comment: create page template and put in your theme, check wordpress template and there you can do whatever you want

Comment: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/